# Creating error messages for grammar mistakes - avoiding duplication when refactoring

Tags: validation, actionscript-3

After my [Dialogue parser](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/80657/parsing-a-dialogue-script-fixing-my-620-line-mess) has parsed a dialogue, it needs to be validated. To that end, I have several checker classes that go through the lines of the Dialogue.

These checker classes get huge as I add more and more features to them. Eventually they get intertwined with checks that they're not really meant to be doing, and I end up with functions the size of 400 lines. This is one of them, and it's the one that I think is easiest to follow.

First off, my `Issue` class, for storing the "error message":

```
public class Issue {
    private var severity:Severity; //See the Severity Enum Class for more details. 
    private var snippet:String;
    private var message:String;
    private var type:String;
    private var relatedLine:Line;

    public function Issue(issueSeverity:Severity, concernedLine:Line, issueSnippet:String, issueMessage:String, issueType:String) {
        severity = issueSeverity;
        relatedLine = concernedLine;
        message = issueMessage;
        type = issueType;
        snippet = issueSnippet;
    }

    public function getRelatedLineNumber():uint {
        return relatedLine.getLineNumber();
    }

    public function getSeverity():Severity {
        return severity;
    }

    public function getSnippet():String {
        return snippet;
    }

    public function getType():String {
        return type;
    }

    public function getMessage():String {
        return message;
    }

    public function printMessage():String {
        return type + " - " + severity.getIDStandardCapitalization() + ": " + message;
    }

    /**
     * For tracing purposes. It works, but it's not nice.
     * @return output regarding the issue.
     */
    public function _debugPrint():String {
        return severity.getID() + " " + type + " Issue relating to Line " + getRelatedLineNumber() + "\n" + "Line " + getRelatedLineNumber() + ": " + relatedLine.getLineAsString() + "\nIssue entails: " + message;
    }
}
```

Printing this message is handled by another class, which is out of scope for this question.

A line looks like this:

```
lineName:"content"
```

The `GrammarChecker` is responsible for checking if the "content" section of the line adheres somewhat to grammar... I can't make any assumptions as to whether the content is English, French, German, Spanish... well, I do know most of them will use a latin character set.

Most of the checks, as you'll see are the same.

The `checkLineOldStyle` function, responsible for validating a line as a string:

```
    private function checkLineOldStyle(l:Line, lineString:String, varsubsReplaced:Boolean = false, dialogue:Dialogue = null, options:Options = null):void {
        if (l.isCommentLine()) {
            if (options == null || options.getSetting("commentfilter")) {
                return;
            }
        }

        var linebreak:String = "";
        if (options != null) {
            linebreak = options.getLineBreak();
        } else {
            linebreak = "\r\n";
        }

        var line:String = l.getRaw();
        var showStrippedVersion:Boolean = false;
        var issue:Issue = null;
        var issueMessageDefault:String = "";
        var lineContainsYOU:Boolean = (l.getRaw().indexOf("YOU") != -1);
        if (lineString != "") {
            if (options != null) {
                if (options.getSetting("substitutes")) {
                    if (varsubsReplaced) {
                        if (lineContainsYOU) {
                            issueMessageDefault = "The following issue was found after replacing variable substitutions, and stripping the line of delay characters and triggers." + linebreak;
                            issueMessageDefault += "Keep in mind that you can place characters in YOU/YOUR/ME/MY variable insertions, like \"Hello*, YOU*!\"." + linebreak;
                        } else {
                            issueMessageDefault = "The following issue was found after replacing variable substitutions, and stripping the line of delay characters and triggers:" + linebreak;
                        }
                    } else {
                        if (lineContainsYOU) {
                            issueMessageDefault = "The following issue was found after stripping the line of delay characters, triggers and variable substitutions." + linebreak;
                            issueMessageDefault += "Keep in mind that you can place characters in YOU/YOUR/ME/MY variable insertions, like \"Hello*, YOU*!\"." + linebreak;
                        } else {
                            issueMessageDefault = "The following issue was found after stripping the line of delay characters, triggers and variable substitutions:" + linebreak;
                        }

                    }
                } else {
                    issueMessageDefault = "The following issue was found after stripping the line of delay characters and triggers:" + linebreak;
                }
            } else {
                if (lineContainsYOU) {
                    issueMessageDefault = "The following issue was found after stripping the line of delay characters, triggers and variable substitutions." + linebreak;
                    issueMessageDefault += "Keep in mind that you can place characters in YOU/YOUR/ME/MY variable insertions, like \"Hello*, YOU*!\"." + linebreak;
                } else {
                    issueMessageDefault = "The following issue was found after stripping the line of delay characters, triggers and variable substitutions:" + linebreak;
                }
            }
            line = lineString;
            showStrippedVersion = true;
        }
        var issueMessage:String = issueMessageDefault;
        var issueSnippet:String = "";
        if (line.indexOf("\"") != -1 && line.indexOf("\"") == line.indexOf("\",")) {
            issueSnippet = StringFunctions.getSnippet(line, "\",");
            issueMessage += "Sentence starting with a comma (grammatical error) on dialogue line on line " + l.getLineNumber() + ", col " + (line.indexOf("\",")) + " near \"" + issueSnippet + "\"" + linebreak;
            issueMessage += l.printLineMessage(linebreak);
            if (showStrippedVersion) {
                issueMessage += "Stripped Line " + l.getLineNumber() + ": " + lineString + linebreak;
            }
            issueMessage += linebreak;
            issue = new Issue(Severity.getEnum("MINOR"), l, issueSnippet, issueMessage, "Grammar");
            addIssue(issue);
            issueMessage = issueMessageDefault;
        }
        if (line.indexOf("\"") != -1 && line.indexOf("\"") == line.indexOf("\"! ")) {
            issueSnippet = StringFunctions.getSnippet(line, "\"! ");
            issueMessage += "Sentence starting with a disconnected exclamation mark (grammatical error) on dialogue line on line " + l.getLineNumber() + ", col " + (line.indexOf("\"! ")) + " near \"" + issueSnippet + "\"" + linebreak;
            issueMessage += l.printLineMessage(linebreak);
            if (showStrippedVersion) {
                issueMessage += "Stripped Line " + l.getLineNumber() + ": " + lineString + linebreak;
            }
            issueMessage += linebreak;
            issue = new Issue(Severity.getEnum("MINOR"), l, issueSnippet, issueMessage, "Grammar");
            addIssue(issue);
            issueMessage = issueMessageDefault;
        }
        if (line.indexOf("\"") != -1 && line.indexOf("\"") == line.indexOf("\". ")) {
            issueSnippet = StringFunctions.getSnippet(line, "\". ");
            issueMessage += "Sentence starting with a disconnected period (grammatical error) on dialogue line on line " + l.getLineNumber() + ", col " + (line.indexOf("\". ")) + " near \"" + issueSnippet + "\"" + linebreak;
            issueMessage += l.printLineMessage(linebreak);
            if (showStrippedVersion) {
                issueMessage += "Stripped Line " + l.getLineNumber() + ": " + lineString + linebreak;
            }
            issueMessage += linebreak;
            issue = new Issue(Severity.getEnum("MINOR"), l, issueSnippet, issueMessage, "Grammar");
            addIssue(issue);
            issueMessage = issueMessageDefault;
        }
        if (line.indexOf(" ,") != -1) {
            issueSnippet = StringFunctions.getSnippet(line, " ,");
            issueMessage += "Space before comma (grammatical error) on dialogue line on line " + l.getLineNumber() + ", col " + (line.indexOf(" ,")) + " near \"" + issueSnippet + "\"" + linebreak;
            issueMessage += l.printLineMessage(linebreak);
            if (showStrippedVersion) {
                issueMessage += "Stripped Line " + l.getLineNumber() + ": " + lineString + linebreak;
            }
            issueMessage += linebreak;
            issue = new Issue(Severity.getEnum("MINOR"), l, issueSnippet, issueMessage, "Grammar");
            addIssue(issue);
            issueMessage = issueMessageDefault;
        }
        if (line.indexOf(",,") != -1) {
            issueSnippet = StringFunctions.getSnippet(line, ",,");
            issueMessage += "Double comma (grammatical error) on dialogue line on line " + l.getLineNumber() + ", col " + (line.indexOf(",,")) + " near \"" + issueSnippet + "\"" + linebreak;
            issueMessage += l.printLineMessage(linebreak);
            if (showStrippedVersion) {
                issueMessage += "Stripped Line " + l.getLineNumber() + ": " + lineString + linebreak;
            }
            issueMessage += linebreak;
            issue = new Issue(Severity.getEnum("MINOR"), l, issueSnippet, issueMessage, "Grammar");
            addIssue(issue);
            issueMessage = issueMessageDefault;
        }
        if (line.indexOf("  ") != -1 && (options == null || !options.getSetting("NoDoubleSpace"))) {
            var splitLine:Array = line.split("\"");
            var doubleSpaceInBadLocation:Boolean = false;
            for (var i:uint = 1, isize:uint = splitLine.length; i < isize; i += 2) { //after first quotation mark, after third, after 5th... blah"HERE blah blah" fff {"HEREset":{"HEREvar":"HEREvalue"}}
                if (splitLine[i].indexOf("  ") != -1) {
                    doubleSpaceInBadLocation = true;
                }
            }
            if (doubleSpaceInBadLocation) { //to prevent lines with whitespace in excess from tripping errors
                issueSnippet = StringFunctions.getSnippet(line, "  ");
                issueMessage += "Double space on line " + l.getLineNumber() + ", col " + (line.indexOf("  ")) + " near \"" + issueSnippet + "\"" + linebreak;
                issueMessage += l.printLineMessage(linebreak);
                if (showStrippedVersion) {
                    issueMessage += "Stripped Line " + l.getLineNumber() + ": " + lineString + linebreak;
                }
                issueMessage += linebreak;
                issue = new Issue(Severity.getEnum("MINOR"), l, issueSnippet, issueMessage, "Grammar");
                addIssue(issue);
                issueMessage = issueMessageDefault;
            }
        }
        if (line.indexOf(" !") != -1 && !l.isIndexInSubstitution(line.indexOf(" !"))) {
            issueSnippet = StringFunctions.getSnippet(line, " !");
            issueMessage += "Grammatical error (space before exclamation mark) on line " + l.getLineNumber() + ", col " + (line.indexOf(" !")) + " near \"" + issueSnippet + "\"" + linebreak;
            issueMessage += l.printLineMessage(linebreak);
            if (showStrippedVersion) {
                issueMessage += "Stripped Line " + l.getLineNumber() + ": " + lineString + linebreak;
            }
            issueMessage += linebreak;
            issue = new Issue(Severity.getEnum("MINOR"), l, issueSnippet, issueMessage, "Grammar");
            addIssue(issue);
            issueMessage = issueMessageDefault;
        }
        if (line.indexOf(" ?") != -1 && !l.isIndexInSubstitution(line.indexOf(" ?"))) {
            issueSnippet = StringFunctions.getSnippet(line, " ?");
            issueMessage += "Grammatical error (space before question mark) on line " + l.getLineNumber() + ", col " + (line.indexOf(" ?")) + " near \"" + issueSnippet + "\"" + linebreak;
            issueMessage += l.printLineMessage(linebreak);
            if (showStrippedVersion) {
                issueMessage += "Stripped Line " + l.getLineNumber() + ": " + lineString + linebreak;
            }
            issueMessage += linebreak;
            issue = new Issue(Severity.getEnum("MINOR"), l, issueSnippet, issueMessage, "Grammar");
            addIssue(issue);
            issueMessage = issueMessageDefault;
        }
        if (line.indexOf(",!") != -1) {
            issueSnippet = StringFunctions.getSnippet(line, ",!");
            issueMessage += "Grammatical error (comma directly before exclamation mark) on line " + l.getLineNumber() + ", col " + (line.indexOf(",!")) + " near \"" + issueSnippet + "\"" + linebreak;
            issueMessage += l.printLineMessage(linebreak);
            if (showStrippedVersion) {
                issueMessage += "Stripped Line " + l.getLineNumber() + ": " + lineString + linebreak;
            }
            issueMessage += linebreak;
            issue = new Issue(Severity.getEnum("MINOR"), l, issueSnippet, issueMessage, "Grammar");
            addIssue(issue);
            issueMessage = issueMessageDefault;
        }
        if (line.indexOf(",?") != -1) {
            issueSnippet = StringFunctions.getSnippet(line, ",?");
            issueMessage += "Grammatical error (comma directly before question mark) on line " + l.getLineNumber() + ", col " + (line.indexOf(",?")) + " near \"" + issueSnippet + "\"" + linebreak;
            issueMessage += l.printLineMessage(linebreak);
            if (showStrippedVersion) {
                issueMessage += "Stripped Line " + l.getLineNumber() + ": " + lineString + linebreak;
            }
            issueMessage += linebreak;
            issue = new Issue(Severity.getEnum("MINOR"), l, issueSnippet, issueMessage, "Grammar");
            addIssue(issue);
            issueMessage = issueMessageDefault;
        }
        if (line.indexOf("!,") != -1) {
            issueSnippet = StringFunctions.getSnippet(line, "!,");
            issueMessage += "Grammatical error (comma directly after exclamation mark) on line " + l.getLineNumber() + ", col " + (line.indexOf("!,")) + " near \"" + issueSnippet + "\"" + linebreak;
            issueMessage += l.printLineMessage(linebreak);
            if (showStrippedVersion) {
                issueMessage += "Stripped Line " + l.getLineNumber() + ": " + lineString + linebreak;
            }
            issueMessage += linebreak;
            issue = new Issue(Severity.getEnum("MINOR"), l, issueSnippet, issueMessage, "Grammar");
            addIssue(issue);
            issueMessage = issueMessageDefault;
        }
        if (line.indexOf("?,") != -1) {
            issueSnippet = StringFunctions.getSnippet(line, "?,");
            issueMessage += "Grammatical error (comma directly after question mark) on line " + l.getLineNumber() + ", col " + (line.indexOf("?,")) + " near \"" + issueSnippet + "\"" + linebreak;
            issueMessage += l.printLineMessage(linebreak);
            if (showStrippedVersion) {
                issueMessage += "Stripped Line " + l.getLineNumber() + ": " + lineString + linebreak;
            }
            issueMessage += linebreak;
            issue = new Issue(Severity.getEnum("MINOR"), l, issueSnippet, issueMessage, "Grammar");
            addIssue(issue);
            issueMessage = issueMessageDefault;
        }
        if (line.indexOf(".,.") != -1) {
            issueSnippet = StringFunctions.getSnippet(line, ".,.");
            issueMessage += "Grammatical error (comma amidst periods: .,.) on line " + l.getLineNumber() + ", col " + (line.indexOf(".,.")) + " near \"" + issueSnippet + "\"" + linebreak;
            issueMessage += l.printLineMessage(linebreak);
            if (showStrippedVersion) {
                issueMessage += "Stripped Line " + l.getLineNumber() + ": " + lineString + linebreak;
            }
            issueMessage += linebreak;
            issue = new Issue(Severity.getEnum("MINOR"), l, issueSnippet, issueMessage, "Grammar");
            addIssue(issue);
            issueMessage = issueMessageDefault;
        } else {
            if (line.indexOf(".,") != -1) {
                if ((line.indexOf("...,") + 2) != line.indexOf(".,")) {
                    issueSnippet = StringFunctions.getSnippet(line, ".,");
                    issueMessage += "Grammatical error (period before comma ending: .,) on line " + l.getLineNumber() + ", col " + (line.indexOf(".,")) + " near \"" + issueSnippet + "\"" + linebreak;
                    issueMessage += l.printLineMessage(linebreak);
                    if (showStrippedVersion) {
                        issueMessage += "Stripped Line " + l.getLineNumber() + ": " + lineString + linebreak;
                    }
                    issueMessage += linebreak;
                    issue = new Issue(Severity.getEnum("MINOR"), l, issueSnippet, issueMessage, "Grammar");
                    addIssue(issue);
                    issueMessage = issueMessageDefault;
                }
            } else if (line.indexOf(",.") != -1) {
                if (line.indexOf(",...") != line.indexOf(",.")) {
                    issueSnippet = StringFunctions.getSnippet(line, ",.");
                    issueMessage += "Grammatical error (comma before period ending: ,.) on line " + l.getLineNumber() + ", col " + (line.indexOf(".,")) + " near \"" + issueSnippet + "\"" + linebreak;
                    issueMessage += l.printLineMessage(linebreak);
                    if (showStrippedVersion) {
                        issueMessage += "Stripped Line " + l.getLineNumber() + ": " + lineString + linebreak;
                    }
                    issueMessage += linebreak;
                    issue = new Issue(Severity.getEnum("MINOR"), l, issueSnippet, issueMessage, "Grammar");
                    addIssue(issue);
                    issueMessage = issueMessageDefault;
                }
            }
        }
        if (line.indexOf(".!.") != -1) {
            issueSnippet = StringFunctions.getSnippet(line, ".!.");
            issueMessage += "Grammatical error (Exclamation mark amidst periods: .!.) on line " + l.getLineNumber() + ", col " + (line.indexOf(".!.")) + " near \"" + issueSnippet + "\"" + linebreak;
            issueMessage += l.printLineMessage(linebreak);
            if (showStrippedVersion) {
                issueMessage += "Stripped Line " + l.getLineNumber() + ": " + lineString + linebreak;
            }
            issueMessage += linebreak;
            issue = new Issue(Severity.getEnum("MINOR"), l, issueSnippet, issueMessage, "Grammar");
            addIssue(issue);
            issueMessage = issueMessageDefault;
        } else {
            if (line.indexOf("!.") != -1) {
                if (line.indexOf("!...") != line.indexOf("!.")) {
                    issueSnippet = StringFunctions.getSnippet(line, "!.");
                    issueMessage += "Grammatical error (double sentence ending: !.) on line " + l.getLineNumber() + ", col " + (line.indexOf("!.")) + " near \"" + issueSnippet + "\"" + linebreak;
                    issueMessage += l.printLineMessage(linebreak);
                    if (showStrippedVersion) {
                        issueMessage += "Stripped Line " + l.getLineNumber() + ": " + lineString + linebreak;
                    }
                    issueMessage += linebreak;
                    issue = new Issue(Severity.getEnum("MINOR"), l, issueSnippet, issueMessage, "Grammar");
                    addIssue(issue);
                    issueMessage = issueMessageDefault;
                }
            }
            if (line.indexOf(".!") != -1) {
                if ((line.indexOf("...!") + 2) != line.indexOf(".!")) {
                    issueSnippet = StringFunctions.getSnippet(line, ".!");
                    issueMessage += "Grammatical error (double sentence ending: .!) on line " + l.getLineNumber() + ", col " + (line.indexOf(".!")) + " near \"" + issueSnippet + "\"" + linebreak;
                    issueMessage += l.printLineMessage(linebreak);
                    if (showStrippedVersion) {
                        issueMessage += "Stripped Line " + l.getLineNumber() + ": " + lineString + linebreak;
                    }
                    issueMessage += linebreak;
                    issue = new Issue(Severity.getEnum("MINOR"), l, issueSnippet, issueMessage, "Grammar");
                    addIssue(issue);
                    issueMessage = issueMessageDefault;
                }
            }
        }
        if (line.indexOf(".?.") != -1) {
            issueSnippet = StringFunctions.getSnippet(line, ".?.");
            issueMessage += "Grammatical error (Question mark amidst periods: .?.) on line " + l.getLineNumber() + ", col " + (line.indexOf(".?.")) + " near \"" + issueSnippet + "\"" + linebreak;
            issueMessage += l.printLineMessage(linebreak);
            if (showStrippedVersion) {
                issueMessage += "Stripped Line " + l.getLineNumber() + ": " + lineString + linebreak;
            }
            issueMessage += linebreak;
            issue = new Issue(Severity.getEnum("MINOR"), l, issueSnippet, issueMessage, "Grammar");
            addIssue(issue);
            issueMessage = issueMessageDefault;
        } else {
            if (line.indexOf("?.") != -1) {
                if (line.indexOf("?...") != line.indexOf("?.")) {
                    issueSnippet = StringFunctions.getSnippet(line, "?.");
                    issueMessage += "Grammatical error (double sentence ending: ?.) on line " + l.getLineNumber() + ", col " + (line.indexOf("?.")) + " near \"" + issueSnippet + "\"" + linebreak;
                    issueMessage += l.printLineMessage(linebreak);
                    if (showStrippedVersion) {
                        issueMessage += "Stripped Line " + l.getLineNumber() + ": " + lineString + linebreak;
                    }
                    issueMessage += linebreak;
                    issue = new Issue(Severity.getEnum("MINOR"), l, issueSnippet, issueMessage, "Grammar");
                    addIssue(issue);
                    issueMessage = issueMessageDefault;
                }
            }
            if (line.indexOf(".?") != -1) {
                if ((line.indexOf("...?") + 2) != line.indexOf(".?")) {
                    issueSnippet = StringFunctions.getSnippet(line, ".?");
                    issueMessage += "Grammatical error (double sentence ending: .?) on line " + l.getLineNumber() + ", col " + (line.indexOf(".?")) + " near \"" + issueSnippet + "\"" + linebreak;
                    issueMessage += l.printLineMessage(linebreak);
                    if (showStrippedVersion) {
                        issueMessage += "Stripped Line " + l.getLineNumber() + ": " + lineString + linebreak;
                    }
                    issueMessage += linebreak;
                    issue = new Issue(Severity.getEnum("MINOR"), l, issueSnippet, issueMessage, "Grammar");
                    addIssue(issue);
                    issueMessage = issueMessageDefault;
                }
            }
        }

        if (line.indexOf("%0A ") != -1) {
            issueSnippet = StringFunctions.getSnippet(line, "%0A ");
            issueMessage += "Space at start of new line on line " + l.getLineNumber() + ", col " + (line.indexOf("%0A ")) + " near \"" + issueSnippet + "\"" + linebreak;
            issueMessage += l.printLineMessage(linebreak);
            if (showStrippedVersion) {
                issueMessage += "Stripped Line " + l.getLineNumber() + ": " + lineString + linebreak;
            }
            issueMessage += linebreak;
            issue = new Issue(Severity.getEnum("MINOR"), l, issueSnippet, issueMessage, "Grammar");
            addIssue(issue);
            issueMessage = issueMessageDefault;
        }
        if (line.indexOf(":\" ") != -1) {
            issueSnippet = StringFunctions.getSnippet(line, ":\" ");
            issueMessage += "Space at start of new line on line " + l.getLineNumber() + ", col " + (line.indexOf(":\" ")) + " near \"" + issueSnippet + "\"" + linebreak;
            issueMessage += l.printLineMessage(linebreak);
            if (showStrippedVersion) {
                issueMessage += "Stripped Line " + l.getLineNumber() + ": " + lineString + linebreak;
            }
            issueMessage += linebreak;
            issue = new Issue(Severity.getEnum("MINOR"), l, issueSnippet, issueMessage, "Grammar");
            addIssue(issue);
            issueMessage = issueMessageDefault;
        }
        if (line.indexOf(" . ") != -1) {
            issueSnippet = StringFunctions.getSnippet(line, " . ");
            issueMessage += "Space before period for new line on line " + l.getLineNumber() + ", col " + (line.indexOf(" . ")) + " near \"" + issueSnippet + "\"" + linebreak;
            issueMessage += l.printLineMessage(linebreak);
            if (showStrippedVersion) {
                issueMessage += "Stripped Line " + l.getLineNumber() + ": " + lineString + linebreak;
            }
            issueMessage += linebreak;
            issue = new Issue(Severity.getEnum("MINOR"), l, issueSnippet, issueMessage, "Grammar");
            addIssue(issue);
            issueMessage = issueMessageDefault;
        }
        if (issue == null) {
            if (lineString == "") {
                if (options == null) {
                    checkLineOldStyle(l, l.getLineStripped(true, true, true), false, dialogue, options);
                } else {
                    checkLineOldStyle(l, l.getLineStripped(true, true, options.getSetting("substitutes")), false, dialogue, options);
                }
            } else if (!varsubsReplaced) {
                if (options == null || options.getSetting("substitutes")) {
                    checkLineOldStyle(l, l.getLineStrippedLiteralSubs(true, true), true, dialogue, options);
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

My issue with this code is that I have a lot of repetition like this:

```
        if (line.indexOf("\"") != -1 && line.indexOf("\"") == line.indexOf("\". ")) {
            issueSnippet = StringFunctions.getSnippet(line, "\". ");
            issueMessage += "Sentence starting with a disconnected period (grammatical error) on dialogue line on line " + l.getLineNumber() + ", col " + (line.indexOf("\". ")) + " near \"" + issueSnippet + "\"" + linebreak;
            issueMessage += l.printLineMessage(linebreak);
            if (showStrippedVersion) {
                issueMessage += "Stripped Line " + l.getLineNumber() + ": " + lineString + linebreak;
            }
            issueMessage += linebreak;
            issue = new Issue(Severity.getEnum("MINOR"), l, issueSnippet, issueMessage, "Grammar");
            addIssue(issue);
            issueMessage = issueMessageDefault;
        }
        if (line.indexOf(" ,") != -1) {
            issueSnippet = StringFunctions.getSnippet(line, " ,");
            issueMessage += "Space before comma (grammatical error) on dialogue line on line " + l.getLineNumber() + ", col " + (line.indexOf(" ,")) + " near \"" + issueSnippet + "\"" + linebreak;
            issueMessage += l.printLineMessage(linebreak);
            if (showStrippedVersion) {
                issueMessage += "Stripped Line " + l.getLineNumber() + ": " + lineString + linebreak;
            }
            issueMessage += linebreak;
            issue = new Issue(Severity.getEnum("MINOR"), l, issueSnippet, issueMessage, "Grammar");
            addIssue(issue);
            issueMessage = issueMessageDefault;
        }
        if (line.indexOf(",,") != -1) {
            issueSnippet = StringFunctions.getSnippet(line, ",,");
            issueMessage += "Double comma (grammatical error) on dialogue line on line " + l.getLineNumber() + ", col " + (line.indexOf(",,")) + " near \"" + issueSnippet + "\"" + linebreak;
            issueMessage += l.printLineMessage(linebreak);
            if (showStrippedVersion) {
                issueMessage += "Stripped Line " + l.getLineNumber() + ": " + lineString + linebreak;
            }
            issueMessage += linebreak;
            issue = new Issue(Severity.getEnum("MINOR"), l, issueSnippet, issueMessage, "Grammar");
            addIssue(issue);
            issueMessage = issueMessageDefault;
        }
```

Every time I declare something I check for, and then make a snippet, message, line, maybe a stripped line, create an issue and add the issue. Then I reset the message to the default. I'm repeating myself over and over, and I'd like to fix that somehow.

`addIssue`, for reference, just stores the issues in an associative array with linenumber as key and a value of issues.

```
    protected function addIssue(i:Issue):void {
        var lineNumber:uint = i.getRelatedLineNumber();
        if (issues[lineNumber] == null) {
            issues[lineNumber] = new Array();
        }
        issues[lineNumber].push(i);
    }
```

I use the issues array for printing issues per-line.

The following things are checked (bit of an old list, might be more):

> ```
> [  ] - Double space is always bad. Can be disabled with #DialogueChecker-NoDoubleSpace#.
> [,,] - Double comma.
> [ ,] - Space in front of comma is a grammatical error.
> [,?] - Grammatical error.
> [,!] - Grammatical error.
> [ !] - Space before exclamation mark is a grammatical error.
> [ ?] - Space before question mark is a grammatical error.
> [!.] - Grammatical error. (Whitelisted: [!...].)
> [?.] - Grammatical error. (Whitelisted: [?...].)
> [%0A ] - Space at start of new line
> [:" ] - Space at start of new line (or you have spaces in your variables - which is not wrong (maybe I could catch this by whitelisting [":" ]))
> [ . ] - Space before end of line is a grammatical error.
> [.!.] - Grammatical error.
> [.?.] - Grammatical error.
> [.?] - Grammatical error, double sentence ending.
> [.,] - Grammatical error, wrongfully continued sentence.
> [.!] - Grammatical error, double sentence ending.
> [.,.] - Grammatical error. Maybe it's a wrongfully typed ellipsis?
> [!,] - Grammatical error, as a finished sentence shouldn't be continued with a comma.
> [?,] - Grammatical error, as a finished sentence shouldn't be continued with a comma.
> [,.] - Grammatical error, as a comma indicates that more text will follow.
> - Lines starting with a comma, as this is not a proper way to begin a sentence.
> - Lines starting with a disconnected exclamation mark [! ].
> - Lines starting with a disconnected period [. ].
> - All of the above, when the following is stripped: 
> -- Anything between asterisks that contain YOU, YOUR, ME or MY (substitutes) 
> -- delay characters ("Б")
> -- triggers (anything between square brackets, game uses these to simulate actions e.g. "Hello.[OPEN_EYES]!" would print as "Hello.!",
> with character eyes being opened between the period and the exclamation mark)
> ```

What I need help with is breaking my `checkLine` function apart. If I try to relocate some of the checks, I end up having to redefine the variables `line`, `issue`, `issueMessage`, `issueSnippet`, `linebreak` and so on. Because of this, I prefer to keep my checks in one function, which will then grow out into a massive bloated function. If I could somehow avoid this boilerplate, I could write functions that handle a set of checks, and make my class read in a more logical manner.

Comment: My code is also on BitBucket these days - https://bitbucket.org/Pim_gd/sdtdialoguechecker/src/eba93259c17c71888ca20a921172b4a40185a6b2/src/GrammarChecker.as?at=master

Answer (score 1):

> This answer doesn't solve my main issue - I'm just writing it to note how I keep making stupid duplicated code.

```
        if (options != null) {
            if (options.getSetting("substitutes")) {
                if (varsubsReplaced) {
                    if (lineContainsYOU) {
                        issueMessageDefault = "The following issue was found after replacing variable substitutions, and stripping the line of delay characters and triggers." + linebreak;
                        issueMessageDefault += "Keep in mind that you can place characters in YOU/YOUR/ME/MY variable insertions, like \"Hello*, YOU*!\"." + linebreak;
                    } else {
                        issueMessageDefault = "The following issue was found after replacing variable substitutions, and stripping the line of delay characters and triggers:" + linebreak;
                    }
                } else {
                    if (lineContainsYOU) {
                        issueMessageDefault = "The following issue was found after stripping the line of delay characters, triggers and variable substitutions." + linebreak;
                        issueMessageDefault += "Keep in mind that you can place characters in YOU/YOUR/ME/MY variable insertions, like \"Hello*, YOU*!\"." + linebreak;
                    } else {
                        issueMessageDefault = "The following issue was found after stripping the line of delay characters, triggers and variable substitutions:" + linebreak;
                    }

                }
            } else {
                issueMessageDefault = "The following issue was found after stripping the line of delay characters and triggers:" + linebreak;
            }
        } else {
            if (lineContainsYOU) {
                issueMessageDefault = "The following issue was found after stripping the line of delay characters, triggers and variable substitutions." + linebreak;
                issueMessageDefault += "Keep in mind that you can place characters in YOU/YOUR/ME/MY variable insertions, like \"Hello*, YOU*!\"." + linebreak;
            } else {
                issueMessageDefault = "The following issue was found after stripping the line of delay characters, triggers and variable substitutions:" + linebreak;
            }
        }
```

If you build the string that changes dynamically, you'll have a much smaller section of code.

You have 4 different things that may or may not be included in the string:
 - replaced substitutes
 - removed substitutes
 - delay characters
 - triggers

replaced and removed substitutes are exclusive to each other. (but you can also have neither)

Delay characters and triggers are ALWAYS in the string.

So if you write

```
var handledVarSubs:Boolean = false;
issueMessageDefault = "The following issue was found after ";
if(options != null){
    if(options.getSetting("substitutes") && varsubsReplaced){
        issueMessageDefault += "replacing variable substitutions, and ";
    }
    handledVarSubs = true;
}
issueMessageDefault += "stripping the line of delay characters";
if(!handledVarSubs){
    issueMessageDefault += ", triggers and variable substitutions";
} else {
    issueMessageDefault += " and triggers";
}
if(lineContainsYOU){
    issueMessageDefault += "." + linebreak;
    issueMessageDefault += "Keep in mind that you can place characters in YOU/YOUR/ME/MY variable insertions, like \"Hello*, YOU*!\"." + linebreak;
} else {
    issueMessageDefault += ":" + linebreak;
}
```

Less duplication, same output.

You can refactor after that - like, `varSubs` are always handled if `options` is not null, so the variable can disappear...

```
issueMessageDefault = "The following issue was found after ";
if(options != null){
    if(options.getSetting("substitutes") && varsubsReplaced){
        issueMessageDefault += "replacing variable substitutions, and ";
    }
}
issueMessageDefault += "stripping the line of delay characters";
if(options != null){
    issueMessageDefault += " and triggers";
} else {
    issueMessageDefault += ", triggers and variable substitutions";
}
if(lineContainsYOU){
    issueMessageDefault += "." + linebreak;
    issueMessageDefault += "Keep in mind that you can place characters in YOU/YOUR/ME/MY variable insertions, like \"Hello*, YOU*!\"." + linebreak;
} else {
    issueMessageDefault += ":" + linebreak;
}
```

and a slight bit of reordering...

```
issueMessageDefault = "The following issue was found after ";
if(options != null){
    if(options.getSetting("substitutes") && varsubsReplaced){
        issueMessageDefault += "replacing variable substitutions, and stripping the line of ";
    }
} else {
    issueMessageDefault += "stripping the line of variable substitutions, ";
}
issueMessageDefault += "delay characters and triggers";
if(lineContainsYOU){
    issueMessageDefault += "." + linebreak;
    issueMessageDefault += "Keep in mind that you can place characters in YOU/YOUR/ME/MY variable insertions, like \"Hello*, YOU*!\"." + linebreak;
} else {
    issueMessageDefault += ":" + linebreak;
}
```